# PROMQL: Calculate the sum_over_time of the product of two instant vectors

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to calculate the `sum_over_time` of the product of two instant vectors:

How can I get this to work?

I tried to use:

```
sum_over_time((metric_a{label1:"A"} \* metric_b{label1:"A"})\[30d\])
```

but I received the error message `"ranges only allowed for vector selectors"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/):

`sum_over_time((metric_a{label1='A'} * metric_b{label1='A'})[30d:])`

(pls note that a default [resolution/step](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/#subqueries) is used in the example, you might want a custom one for your query)

---

In Prometheus, you can do this to get a range vector:

`metric[1m]`

However, you cannot do this with expression:

`(metric)[1m]` ---> `parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors`

Instead, a subquery should be used:

`(metric)[1m:]`